# Changing row background using xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, formatting, xlsxwriter

I have an excel wit n rows and 10 columns. To change background of a particular row , I used :

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandasEx.xlsx',  engine ='xlsxwriter') 
# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object
df.to_excel(writer, index=False)
# Get the xlsxwriter objects from the dataframe writer object.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

cell_format = workbook.add_format()
cell_format.set_bg_color('green')
worksheet.set_row(rowNo, cell_format=cell_format)
```

but the formatting exceeds the 10 columns and goes beyond them. How to keep the formatting limited to 10 columns? Or in general, How to keep the formatting limited to columns which are used?

P.S. : I found out about [conditional_format](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html) but i dont understand which `type` value should i choose?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34026362/xlswriter-formatting-a-range

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for my case. This changes the background without any criteria.

```
worksheet.conditional_format(row,0,row,lastCol, {'type':'no_blanks', 'format': cell_format})
```