# Add format method in xlsxwriter multiple formats

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am trying the following code and it is working well. But I am wondering if there is a short approach to deal with the add format feature which is there in the package of xlsxwriter.
Here's the code to more clarification

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_excel.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
new_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

workbook  = writer.book

format_right_to_left = workbook.add_format()
format_right_to_left.set_reading_order(2)

myformat = workbook.add_format()
myformat.set_reading_order(2)
myformat.set_align('center')
myformat.set_align('vcenter')

worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
worksheet.right_to_left()

worksheet.set_column('B:G', 12, myformat)
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 16, myformat)
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

In the code I have those lines of adding format

```
myformat = workbook.add_format()
myformat.set_reading_order(2)
myformat.set_align('center')
myformat.set_align('vcenter')
```

My question how to shorten such lines so as to be more flexible and so as to be able to add more and more formats in an easy way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass properties as a dict to `add_format()`.

```
my_format = workbook.add_format({'reading_order':2, 'align':'center', 'valign':'vcenter'})
```

You can [read more here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html)

EDIT: full working example, with border

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

data = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

with pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_excel.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    workbook  = writer.book
    my_format = workbook.add_format({'reading_order':2, 'align':'center', 'valign':'vcenter', 'border':1})
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
    worksheet.set_column('B:G', 12, my_format)
    worksheet.set_column('A:A', 16, my_format)
```

Comment: Question: How can I put borders for the current region of A1 ( the number of rows would be dynamic but the columns would be 7)?

Comment: And as for these two lines `writer.save()
writer.close()` Is that right or using `workbook` variable is the right ??

Comment: It would be better to use `with` context manager as shown in the docs, that will take care to close the file for you. Note the note: __None of the methods and properties are considered public.__

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried this after some search `formater = workbook.add_format({'border': 1})
worksheet.set_column('A:G', 15, formater)` but doesn't seem to work for me!!

Comment: Amazing. Thanks a lot. But the borders are on the whole column. How can I set the borders for specific range (A1:C3) for example?

Comment: I have searched a lot of how to set range reference but didn't find a clue till now. I mean I need to apply the format on specific range not the whole columns.

Comment: [it's not possible to set format to multiple cells at once](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/faq.html#q-can-i-apply-a-format-to-a-range-of-cells-in-one-go). You either format column, row or single cell. You need to loop over single cells and set format one by one. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34026362/xlswriter-formatting-a-range

Comment: Can you show me a simple example of how to loop over cells for a specific range?